# I want to print first letter from string and then print characters after whitespaces in lowercase without using split function

Tags: java

Here is my question: I want to print like this without using split function

Input: Rushikesh Balchand Chaudhari

Output: Rushikesh.b.c

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Rushikesh  Balchand Chaudhari";
    String [] arr = str.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(arr[0]);
    for(int i =1 ; i < arr.length ;i++){
        builder.append(".");
        builder.append(arr[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0));
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: What appears in `str1.substring(str1.indexOf(" "),1` if str1 has no blank?

Comment: You have modified original string in first place after if block. Now there are not spaces. indexOf now will return -1.

Answer (score 1):

Here your answer

```
 String h="Number Of White Spaces";
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList< Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<h.length();i++){

        if(h.charAt(i)==' '){

                al.add(i);
        }
    }

    for(int l=0;l<al.size();l++){
        int a=al.get(l);    
        if(l==0){
            sb.append(h.substring(l,a));
            sb.append('.');
            sb.append(h.substring(a+1,a+2).toLowerCase());
        }
        else{

            sb.append('.');
        sb.append(h.substring(a+1, a+2).toLowerCase()); 
        }
    }


System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**OUTPUT-->**
Number.o.w.s

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code::

You just need to check with the index and have some Boolean values it will serve the purpose.

You can also optimize this code.

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Rushikesh Balchand Chaudhari";
        boolean isWhiteSpace = false;
        boolean afterWhitespace = false;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' '){
                isWhiteSpace =true;
                afterWhitespace = true;
            }
            else if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                if(!afterWhitespace){
                    builder.append(str.charAt(i));
                }
                if(isWhiteSpace && afterWhitespace){
                    builder.append(".");
                    builder.append(str.toLowerCase().charAt(i));
                    isWhiteSpace = false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
}
```